# Complex Numbers: Solve for $z^8-z^4+1 = 0$.

Tags: complex-numbers

This is what I currently have. I'm not sure how to continue. Can someone show or teach me how it's done? A repost because there were flaws with formatting.
Work:

\begin{array}{*{20}c} {x = \frac{{  1 \pm \sqrt {1-4} }}{{2}}} \\ \end{array}

\begin{array}{*{20}c} {x = \frac{{ 1 \pm{i}\sqrt {-3} }}{{2}}} \\ \end{array}

$$z^4 ={r^4(\cos(4θ))(\sin(4θ)}$$

Comment: You could edit your previous question.

Comment: How is $x$ related to $z$?

Comment: Since $z^2-z+1=\Phi_6(z)$ we have $z^8-z^4+1=\Phi_{24}(z)$ and the roots of the given polynomial are the primitive $24$th roots of unity, i.e. $\zeta^1,\zeta^5,\zeta^7,\zeta^{11},\zeta^{13},\zeta^{17},\zeta^{19},\zeta^{23}$ with $\zeta=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{24}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{12}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left[(\sqrt{3}+1)+i(\sqrt{3}-1)\right].$